# Merge two dataframes and keep the common values while retaining values based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

When I merge two dataframes, it keeps the columns from the left and the right dataframes
with a _x and _y appended.
But I want it to make it one column and 'merge' the values of the two columns such that:

1. when the values are the same it just puts that one value
2. when the values are different it keeps the value based on another column called 'date'
   and takes the value which is the 'latest' based on the date.

I also tried doing it using concatenate and in this case it does 'merge' the two columns, but it just seems to 'append' the two rows.

In the code below for example, I would like to get as output the dataframe df_desired. How can I get that?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(30)

company1 = ('comA','comB','comC','comD')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=None)
df1['company'] = company1
df1['clv']=[100,200,300,400]
df1['date'] = [20191231,20191231,20191001,20190931]
print("\ndf1:")
print(df1)

company2 = ('comC','comD','comE','comF')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=None)
df2['company'] = company2
df2['clv']=[300,450,500,600]
df2['date'] = [20191231,20191231,20191231,20191231]

print("\ndf2:")
print(df2)

df_desired = pd.DataFrame(columns=None)
df_desired['company'] = ('comA','comB','comC','comD','comE','comF')
df_desired['clv']=[100,200,300,450,500,600]
df_desired['date'] = [20191231,20191231,20191231,20191231,20191231,20191231]
print("\ndf_desired:")
print(df_desired)

df_merge = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on = 'company',
        right_on = 'company',how='outer')
print("\ndf_merge:")
print(df_merge)
# alternately
df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
print("\ndf_concat:")
print(df_concat)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to `concat` the two dataframes then sort the concatenated dataframe on `date` in ascending order and drop the duplicate entries(*while keeping the latest entry*) based on company:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
df = df.sort_values('date', na_position='first').drop_duplicates('company', keep='last', ignore_index=True)
```

Result:

```
  company  clv       date
0    comA  100 2019-12-31
1    comB  200 2019-12-31
2    comC  300 2019-12-31
3    comD  450 2019-12-31
4    comE  500 2019-12-31
5    comF  600 2019-12-31
```

Comment: @alpha-delta Does this answered your question?